# Deleting values in a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I need to structure a groupby where I retain all of the records with the minimum value in that given group, and drop the rest. The number of values per group could vary. How could I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO; instead of providing an abstract question here's a suggestions: (1) show what you have, (2) what you want to have and (3) what you have done that didnt work.

Comment: `m = df['record'].eq(df.groupby('key')['record'].transform('min')) ` and then `df.loc[m]` or `df.where(m)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def keepmins(df, col):
    return df[df[col] == df[col].min()]

dlist = []
for i, j in df.groupby(col2):
    dlist.append(keepmins(j, col)

pd.concat(dlist)
```